# Build custom objects from DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to loop through data to build a list of objects that each has a list of objects. Here's what the data looks like

```
AccountID    AccountName    ListItem
------------------------------------
1            Foo            Item1
1            Foo            Item2
2            Test           Value1
2            Test           Value2
2            Test           Value3
3            Bar            List1
3            Bar            List2
3            Bar            List3
```

The other posts I've seen didn't quite tackle my issue. From my data, I would expect to create 3 `Account` objects, each having a `List<string>` of the ListItem data.

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
var accountGroups = myDataTable.GroupBy(x=>x.Field<string>("AccountName"));
```

and then loop through accountGroups to add the ListItems, but of course DataTable doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Is this possible with LINQ or should I just write the loop manually?

Comment: you can make it `myDataTable.Rows.GroupBy(..)` or `myDataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `DataTable` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Not directly, but there's an `AsEnumerable()` extension method in `System.Data.DataRowExtensions` that will turn it into an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.

```
var accountGroups = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                               .GroupBy(x=>x.Field<string>("AccountName"))
                               .Select(g => new Account {
                                    AccountName = g.Key,
                                    List = g.Select(g => g.Field<string>("ListItem").ToList()
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

> but of course DataTable doesn't implement IEnumerable

You can use the extension method `AsEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable<List<string>> accountListItems = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("AccountName"))
    .Select(g => g.Select(row => row.Field<string>("ListItem")).ToList());
```